# code for calling from iphone os 3.0 not working?

Tags: iphone

NSString *StrPhoneNo = @"(21) 2197-78797";

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
      [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", StrPhoneNo]];
```

This is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The phone number doesn't look correct to me. I don't know where you're located, but I guess you need a 0 or 1 in front of the phone number. Or if it's an international number, add a "+" in front of the country code.

Answer (score 0):

In my code I'm calling "+353876543210" and it's working fine. So I guess the phone number is in the wrong format.